# Sort by the most recent to the oldest in Azure Cosmos Table not working

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

According to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern, if save RowKey to string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
then I can always pick the most recent record by using  azure.TableQuery().top(1);

But actually it's not works like there, the most recent add row unable to be pick up. I tested it by manually adding two rows, with Rowkey in following values 2518658399914874511 and 2518658399901330034. Please advise.

Comment: Please share more details, e.g. the source code.

Comment: I just use the above code in the article string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);  I created two invertedTicks and then manually insert it to a Azure Cosmos Table collection, so  I have two records in the Table, but they just ordered by the timestamp not the rowKey.

Comment: Could you please share your source code?

Comment: using System;

namespace TestDate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           

            string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
           

        }
    }
}

Comment: It's not the full source code, could you please add the full one into the question with graceful format?